# Overlay elements in web page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a web page with a jQuery menu like [this](http://www.egrappler.com/jqsimplemenu/index.html) and jQuery accordions. My problem is that the accordion overlay the menu (like [this](http://prntscr.com/3b4qru)) and I want that the menu overlay the accordion.

The code of the accordion is

```
            <div id="accordionDatos" class="fondo ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset" role="tablist">

                <h3 class="fondo ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-accordion-icons ui-corner-all" role="tab" id="ui-accordion-accordion-header-0" aria-controls="ui-accordion-accordion-panel-0" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>Datos personales</h3>
                <div class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" style="display: none;" id="ui-accordion-accordion-panel-0" aria-labelledby="ui-accordion-accordion-header-0" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true">
                               .......
                </div>      

            </div>
```

The class "fondo" is .fondo {z-index: 100;}. I put this class in div element and in h3 element (the title of the accordion tab).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the css. there might chance to over write the z-index and use position:relative with the same.

if you want an element on top of another. Z-index of the element need to be in order.

ex : top element z-index: 2 , bottom element z-index should be less than 2.

```
  #accordion {z-index:999; position:relatevie }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: The mistake is that I need the accordion in the background, so I put z-index: 0; position:relative and works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `#accordion {z-index:100;}`

Comment: I try this and I put .menu {z-index:0;} but didn't work... :S

Comment: can you post your html code pls. Or be sure your displayed text's div doesn't have bigger z-index

Comment: The mistake is that I need the accordion in the background, so I put z-index: 0; position:relative and works fine!

Comment: I was thinking that you want the accordion in front :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the CSS z-index property: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp